# Calculating total revenue lost in returns with Superstore dataset

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I am attempting to create a parameter that allows me to custom filter for Sales, Units, Profit, Orders, Returns, and Return Units. I'm running into an issue when creating the calculated field that calculates return $ and return units. The result I am getting doesn't seem to be accurate.

I have created a Parameter with the above list called `[Choose KPI]`.

I thought I would be able to create calculated fields for `[Returned $]` and `[Returned Units]`:

`IF [Returned] = 'Yes' THEN [Sales] END` 
and
`IF [Returned] = 'Yes' THEN [Quantity] END`

Which would make my calculated field for `[Choose KPI]`:

```
CASE [Parameters].[Choose KPI]
WHEN "Sales" THEN SUM([Sales])
WHEN "Units" THEN SUM([Quantity])
WHEN "Profit" THEN SUM([Profit])
WHEN "Orders" THEN COUNT([Order ID])
WHEN "Returns" THEN SUM([Returns $])
WHEN "Return Units" THEN SUM([Returned Units])
END
```

Rather than returns being associated with product ID, they appear to be linked only with the order ID, which creates duplicate values when there were multiple items on an order (are we assuming all items in the order were returned when `[Returned] = 'Yes'`?), causing the sum of `[Returns $]` to be inflated.

How can I create a filter that uses the distinct Order ID to calculate total returns and returned units?

Answer (score -1):

In Tableau, you can use the "Group" option in the "Analysis" menu to create a new field that groups your data by the "Order ID" field. Then, you can use the "COUNTD" function to count the number of unique "Order ID" values, which will give you the total number of returned orders.

To calculate the total returned units, you can create a calculated field that multiplies the quantity of each returned item by the number of unique items returned per order. You can use the COUNTD([Order ID]) and SUM(IF [Returned] = 'Yes' THEN [Quantity] END) in the calculation.

In the [Choose KPI] field, you can use the following calculation:

```
CASE [Parameters].[Choose KPI]
WHEN "Sales" THEN SUM([Sales])
WHEN "Units" THEN SUM([Quantity])
WHEN "Profit" THEN SUM([Profit])
WHEN "Orders" THEN COUNTD([Order ID])
WHEN "Returns" THEN SUM(IF [Returned] = 'Yes' THEN [Sales] END)
WHEN "Return Units" THEN SUM(IF [Returned] = 'Yes' THEN [Quantity] END) * COUNTD([Order ID])
END
```

This way, you will be able to filter your data based on the different KPIs you've defined, and the calculations for returned sales and units will be based on the distinct Order ID values.

*(Answer by https://chat.openai.com/chat and formatted by me.)*

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, this doesn't quite work, as Tableau doesn't recognize DISTINCT as a function. This would also remove returns of the same value even if the Order ID was different.

Comment: @Chase - tried once more, if it does not work, I will delete the answer as it is probably a spam.